# Unable to wrap shared pointer over ncurses WINDOW raw pointer returned by newwin()

Tags: c++, pointers, ncurses

I am using ncurses in one of my projects. Creating windows in ncurses by the newwin() function returns a WINDOW* pointer. I want to avoid the use of raw pointers in my code as it is not best practice and was trying to wrap it in a shared pointer. But doing so throws segmentation fault.

This code runs fine with no seg fault:

```
#include "ncurses.h"
#include <memory>
int main()
{

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    
    auto win = newwin(10,10,0,0);
    //std::shared_ptr<WINDOW> sh_ptr = std::make_shared<WINDOW>(*win);
    //auto win1 = sh_ptr.get();
    
    mvwaddstr(win,0,2, "hello");
    wrefresh(win);
    getch();

    
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

This code throws seg fault:

```
#include "ncurses.h"
#include <memory>
int main()
{

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    
    auto win = newwin(10,10,0,0);
    std::shared_ptr<WINDOW> sh_ptr = std::make_shared<WINDOW>(*win);
    auto win1 = sh_ptr.get();
    
    mvwaddstr(win1,0,2, "hello");
    wrefresh(win1);
    getch();

    
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The shared_ptr will destroy the `WINDOW*` using `delete`.  It needs to destroy it using `delwin`.  You'll need to plumb that up.

Comment: Using raw pointers is not bad practice. People often make confusion between using raw pointers and using `new`. In other words, non-owning raw pointers are perfectly fine. When ownership is involved, indeed it is better to use RAII. (I don't know this lib though I don't know in which case we are here, it was just to clear things up)

Comment: You cannot just wrap any old pointer with a smart pointer. You need to know how that pointer should be deallocated, and make sure that the smart pointer you choose will do that correctly.

Comment: It may be easier to just write your own RAII wrapper around this pointer than to create a dedicated allocator to pass to `std::shared_ptr` (putting aside that you don't seem to need shared ownership here)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter seems like a possibility.

Comment: It seems to be a better choice indeed

Comment: thanks for the inputs folks, seems like custom deleter is required here. and @Fareanor that makes sense, i will check once again if using raw pointers might be ok after all in my use case.

Comment: This doesn't wrap the WINDOW - it makes a new WINDOW, copies the values from the old WINDOW and then wraps that one.